# How can I tell which account is currently logged into Windows 7, remotely?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

With Windows XP, when I try remotely logging into a workstation that has another user logged in, it tells me who that is. With Windows 7, however, it just says "another user is currently…"  without telling me *who* that is.

Is there a way to tell which account is logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [this 'feature' is by design](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/92ff9748-b3d3-4424-8980-702b052a677a/).  I know this doesn't help you, but it's the only answer I could see.

Comment: thats what my google searches revealed - I was hoping there was an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Start *Computer Management* on your computer.
- Right-click on *Computer Mangement (Local)* and choose *Connect to another computer..*
- Put in the name of the workstation you want to see remote session logs of:

  ```
  System Tools\Event Viewer\Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager\Operational\
  ```